# how does one use lightening ear buds with new MacBook Pro?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro

My iPhone 7 came with ear buds that use lightening port.

My new MacBook Pro has old style analog headphone jack.

Do I convert back to analog or go thru usbc?

Comment: You can go [Lightning to 3.5mm Jack](http://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MMX62FE/A/lightning-to-35mm-headphone-jack-adapter) or [Lightning to USB-C](http://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MK0X2AM/A/usb-c-to-lightning-cable-1m)

So .... what is your question?

Comment: neither of those items would solve the problem. The first link you post would allow an iPhone 7 to accept analog headphones. Not what I'm trying to do. The 2nd link you posted would plug into the MacBook Pro usb port but provide a male lightning end and I need a female lighting end. See I have ear buds than end with lightning male. There is no lightening female port on new MacBook Pro.

Comment: Sorry I got things (male/female ends) mixed up. The closest thing that MAY work is a male USB to Female Lightning that is often used as Apple Pen charger... whether it will work for audio or not I don't know. Good luck in your search.

Comment: that's okay, just be careful IRL never to get male/female ends mixed up. lol.